# Why does this function return an error?

Tags: r, function

I'm diagnosing a function and finally found that the error comes from this piece such like:

```
# Function
miss<-function(formula, data, method="glm", family="binomial"){

    if (method=="glm"){
            fit1<-glm(formula,data=data,family=family)
            xmatrix<-model.matrix(fit1,na.action=na.pass)
            coef<-coef(fit1)
            vcov<-vcov(fit1)
       }
   return(fit1)
} 

# test data 
set.seed(2014)
df<-data.frame(
group=rbinom(100,1,0.6),
sex=rbinom(100,1,0.3),
y=rbinom(100,1,0.8))

miss(y~group+sex,data=df, method="glm",family="binomial")
Error in data.frame(bv_aer_f7r = list(sid = c(1016L, 1022L, 1031L, 1036L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 96 ....
```

Does somebody have ideas what's wrong of my function?

Comment: Two things: use `glm(formula(formula),data=data,family=family)` in your glm call in miss fucntion and pass the formula argument as a string ie `miss('y~group+sex',data=df, method="glm",family="binomial")`

Comment: Thanks. It does help! Is there a way I can just use `y~group+sex` rather than a string in the miss function? Also how could I pass the `...` for `glm` in the `miss` function? Could you give an answer? +1

Comment: Yes, but the entire function does need this model.matrix output for the following issues.

Comment: sorry ignore previous comment (now deleted) - no i don't know how to pass it not as a string without model.matrix throwing an error. Annoying

Comment: Remove the na.action=na.pass from the model.matrix call and it runs without the formula being in a string.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. na.action=na.pass is necessary to return the model.matrix in the same length of the data, otherwise it just returns the complete cases by excluding rows with NA. In my case I have to use this argument.